# Report Builder parameters vs filters

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Good day

I am trying to figure out what is the difference between a filter and a parameter.
Currently I have a report and I edited the query and placed a where clause.So when running the report I see that I need to provide a parameter.This is great, but I don't see the report until I have entered some value in the parameter.How can I get it that by load/default the whole report is shown and then when typing a value in the parameter box that it then filters.

Comment: Try setting the parameter(s) to `Allow Null`

Comment: I tried that, but then I still see an empty report.I do see the Column headers of the report, but with no data

Comment: Try also changing the where clause to allow 'optional parameters' such as `WHERE (@param IS NULL OR col = @param)`